# asp: Request.Form.GetValues not fetching javascript-generated checkbox values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am using jQuery's .serialize() to fetch values from javascript-generated checkboxes. After serialization, the data is sent via AJAX to an aspx page. the aspx page should then capture the checkbox values with Request.Form.GetValues[]. My problem is that the checkboxes are serialized but the Request.Form.GetValues[] does not get any values.

I used to have the checkboxes generated in the web form which worked fine. But when they became javascript-generated, the Request.Form.GetValues[] can no longer fetch the checkbox values.

Here are the code snippets:

(serialize and ajax functions)

```
$('a#upload-button-gp').live('click', function() {
var data = $('form#upload').serialize();
$.loader(true);
$.ajax({
    url: '/ptcProject/ajax.aspx',
    type: 'post',
    data: { data: data, upload: 1 },
    success: function(response) {
        if (parseInt(response) == 1) {
            $.loader(false);
            $('#confirmationUpload').modal('hide');
        }
        else if (parseInt(response) == 0) {
            alert("You have already uploaded this batch.");
            $('#confirmationUpload').modal('hide');
            $.loader(false);
        }
        else {
            alert('Please select at least one row to upload.');
            $('#confirmationUpload').modal('hide');
            $.loader(false);
        }
    }
});
```

(js-generated checkboxes)

```
$('tbody#table-data').append("<tr><td><input id='check' name='include[]' type='checkbox' class='input-field checkbox' value='" + buttonId + "' checked='checked' /></td>" + $(this).parent().parent().html() + "</tr>");
```

(aspx page)

```
string[] claimsID = Request.Form.GetValues("include[]");
```

your help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

found out the problem!

added code:

```
data += "&upload=1";
...
$.ajax({
...
data: data,
...
```

that was it. thank you for all who answered!

Comment: What is the response datatype?

Comment: Does it help to know that unchecked checkboxes don't generate a value at all in Request.Forms.GetValues?

Comment: @lbu the response is an integer. I must apologize that I failed to include the error upon ajax request (_Object reference not set to an instance of an object._)

Comment: @MushinNoShin the checkboxes are checked...

Comment: You should bring the answer out of your question and submit it as the answer to the question and mark it as the answer.  Just some SO etiquette :)